# cannot use PrimeVUE table in VUE 3

Tags: vue.js, recursion, primevue

I follow the official tuturial of table from PrimeVUE.
But the page is broken and it looks like the recursion issue.
Did anyone face the same issue before?

```
<template>
    <div>
        <DataTable :value="products" responsiveLayout="scroll">
            <Column field="code" header="Code"></Column>
            <Column field="name" header="Name"></Column>
        </DataTable>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import ProductService from '../services/ProductService';

export default {
    setup() {
        onMounted(() => {
        //productService.value.getProducts().then(data => products.value = data);
        products.value = 
            [
                {"id": "1000","code": "f230fh0g3","name": "Bamboo Watch","description": "Product Description","image": "bamboo-watch.jpg","price": 65,"category": "Accessories","quantity": 24,"inventoryStatus": "INSTOCK","rating": 5},
                {"id": "1001","code": "nvklal433","name": "Black Watch","description": "Product Description","image": "black-watch.jpg","price": 72,"category": "Accessories","quantity": 61,"inventoryStatus": "INSTOCK","rating": 4}    
            ]
        }
        )

        let products = ref();
        const productService = ref(new ProductService());

        return { products, productService }
    }
};
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using the same but it's working, how did you define the DataTable? Did you use ```Vue.use(DataTable)``` or not? If not, try to. Or you can define the component in the setup by adding components property to export default and writing DataTable inside of it

Comment: The error says what's the problem. You use Column but didn't import or register it

Comment: Thank you! My problem has been resolved!